# Pandas - conditionally select source column of data for a new column based on row value

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a pandas function that allows selection from different columns based on a condition? This is analogous to a CASE statement in a SQL Select clause. For example, say I have the following DataFrame:

```
foo = DataFrame(
    [['USA',1,2],
    ['Canada',3,4],
    ['Canada',5,6]], 
    columns = ('Country', 'x', 'y')
)
```

I want to select from column 'x' when Country=='USA', and from column 'y' when Country=='Canada', resulting in something like the following:

```
  Country  x  y  z
0     USA  1  2  1
1  Canada  3  4  4
2  Canada  5  6  6

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Where does column `z` come from?

Comment: z would be the "combined" column, from column x or y depending on Country

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html?highlight=where#pandas.DataFrame.where)'s `other` argument and [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> foo = pd.DataFrame([
...     ['USA',1,2],
...     ['Canada',3,4],
...     ['Canada',5,6]
... ], columns=('Country', 'x', 'y'))
>>>
>>> z = foo['x'].where(foo['Country'] == 'USA', foo['y'])
>>> pd.concat([foo['Country'], z], axis=1)
  Country  x
0     USA  1
1  Canada  4
2  Canada  6
```

If you want `z` as column name, specify `keys`:

```
>>> pd.concat([foo['Country'], z], keys=['Country', 'z'], axis=1)
  Country  z
0     USA  1
1  Canada  4
2  Canada  6
```

Comment: I switched my answer to this from @EdChum's answer, because it is easier to read and more performant.

Answer (score 5):

This would work:

```
In [84]:

def func(x):
    if x['Country'] == 'USA':
        return x['x']
    if x['Country'] == 'Canada':
        return x['y']
    return NaN
foo['z'] = foo.apply(func(row), axis = 1)
foo
Out[84]:
  Country  x  y  z
0     USA  1  2  1
1  Canada  3  4  4
2  Canada  5  6  6

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

You can use `loc`:

```
In [137]:

foo.loc[foo['Country']=='Canada','z'] = foo['y']
foo.loc[foo['Country']=='USA','z'] = foo['x']
foo
Out[137]:
  Country  x  y  z
0     USA  1  2  1
1  Canada  3  4  4
2  Canada  5  6  6

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

**EDIT**

Although unwieldy using `loc` will scale better with larger dataframes as the apply here is called for every row whilst using boolean indexing will be vectorised.

Comment: Yeah I had written a similar function. I was wondering if pandas had something baked in that works like this, rather than having to write a function, as this is something I do often.

Comment: The other way would be to use boolean indexing see my answer

Comment: I don't think using loc works, since boolean masking always produces a copy of the DataFrame, rather than a view.

Comment: That is only true if the column already exists I think as I get no warning unless the column exists, I did some timings and using `loc` method is 1.66ms for a data frame size of 3000 rows versus the apply method which takes 60.2 ms

Comment: Notice how there's no z column using the loc method? ;)

Comment: I've added a way you can use `loc` now, the key is to do the first assignment to the new column which will produce `NaN`s and then you can do the boolean masking again and select the column in `loc`

Comment: @EdChum you don't need to makes the rows on the rhs side, e.g. you can just do ``df['y']`` (as it will align the lhs and rhs). Also no need to create z before hand (and the loc will create it). (this is in 0.14rc1; might have been buggy before that)

Comment: @Jeff can you explain how, when I did this it didn't work: `foo.loc[foo['Country'] == 'USA','z'] = foo.loc[foo['Country']=='USA', 'x']
foo.loc[foo['Country'] == 'Canada','z'] = foo.loc[foo['Country']=='Canada', 'y']` with and without using `loc` on the left hand side

Comment: @Jeff this only updated the last operation `foo['z'] = foo.loc[foo['Country']=='USA', 'x']
foo['z'] = foo.loc[foo['Country']=='Canada', 'y']` so the first assignment is overwritten which is why I used a boolean mask in my answer

Comment: @EdChum ``foo.loc[foo['Country']=='Canada','z'] = foo['y']`` (works even if you don't assign z first)

Comment: @Jeff yes, as always you are right I will update my answer, thanks for the explanation, I thought you needed to mask on the right hand side too, didn't think it would be clever enough to align correctly

Comment: hah, no by definition the rhs will be aligned with the left, if you don't want this then you need to make it an array

Comment: if you are only doing 1 or the other , this will work as well: ``foo['z'] = foo['y'].where(foo['Country']=='Canada',foo['x'])``

Comment: yep care to put an issue up?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic solution to selecting arbitrary columns given a value in another column.

This has the additional benefit of separating the lookup logic in a simple `dict` structure which makes it easy to modify.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['UK', 'burgers', 4, 5, 6],
    ['USA', 4, 7, 9, 'make'],
    ['Canada', 6, 4, 6, 'you'],
    ['France', 3, 6, 'fat', 8]],
    columns = ('Country', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
)
```

I extend to an operation where a conditional result is stored in an external lookup structure (`dict`)

```
lookup = {'Canada': 'd', 'France': 'c', 'UK': 'a', 'USA': 'd'}
```

Loop the `pd.DataFrame` for each column stored in the `dict` and use the values in the condition table to determine which column to select

```
for k,v in lookup.iteritems():
    filt = df['Country'] == k
    df.loc[filt, 'result'] = df.loc[filt, v] # modifies in place
```

To give the life lesson

```
In [69]: df
Out[69]:
  Country        a  b    c     d   result
0      UK  burgers  4    5     6  burgers
1     USA        4  7    9  make     make
2  Canada        6  4    6   you      you
3  France        3  6  fat     8      fat
```

Comment: This is working but I'm getting a warning saying ```A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead```  Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: I wouldn’t worry. We want that to happen. You can get rid of it by adding ‘.copy()’ to that line but it’s not necessary

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.select](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) is perfect for that job, especially with multiple choices. It works well in dataframes:

```
conditions = [
    foo['Country'] == 'USA', 
    foo['Country'] == 'Canada',
]

choices = [
    foo['x'],
    foo['y'],
]

foo['z'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default = pd.NA)
```

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! Especially for people used to SQL 'DECODE' syntax since it closely mirrors it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
temp1 = foo[(foo['Country'] == 'Canada')][['Country', 'y']].rename(columns={'y': 'z'})
temp2 = foo[(foo['Country'] == 'USA')][['Country', 'x']].rename(columns={'x': 'z'})
wanted_df = pd.concat([temp1, temp2])
```